# Am getting this error when i upload my website to cpanel a codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, cpanel

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74/ci_session8c890fa70e8c2a9726a00d721269c80de8117d50): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 174

Backtrace:

File: /home/propert6/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74)

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 143

Backtrace:

File: /home/propert6/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

What is listed in the php.ini file for session.save_path ?

Most likely you'd find this (depending on your configuration) in cPanel>>Software>>MultiPHP INI Editor

You can create a php info page to get this information (importanly whether the value is set locally or globally for that version of PHP) as well as the .ini file files loaded into the configuration

You may also want to check the following:

/home/$user/public_html/.htaccess
/home/user/public_html/*.ini